# HtmlAgilityPack doesn't return text inside a div

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here is the sample html page,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <span>This is a Test message</span>
        <span id="slogan">A sample slogan <br /> with 2 lines.</span>
    </div>
    <div id="news">
        This is a test news
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my C# code,

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("URL", DownLoadCompleted);

    }

    void DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
    {
        if(e.Error == null)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = e.Document;

            if (doc != null)
            {
                var newsdiv = (from divnode in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                               where divnode.Attributes["id"].Value == "header"
                               select divnode).FirstOrDefault();

                var txtT = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(newsdiv.InnerText);
                txtDisplay.Text = txtT;

            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to retrieve the innerText of `header` div it works. But when I try the same code to retrieve innertext of `topContainer` div it doesn't return anything. It doesn't throw an error as well. And it don't work at all for `<span>` elements.

What could be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Consider adding sample HTML element that show the problem.

Comment: Sorry for less information. I just added a HTML code snippet. and more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trhying to select only div with ID `IDOFTHEDIV`; therefore other DIV with other ID's (or without ID's) won't be selected

Comment: When I change the ID to an id of another div, it doesn't work sometimes.